# How to show sap.tnt.SideNavigation over the view content on mobile?

Tags: mobile, sapui5, sidebar

In the mobile mode, the `sap.tnt.SideNavigation` controller can be either expanded or collapsed (`expanded = "true"/"false"`). The problem is that when the sidebar expanded, it shifts the view content aside:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to show the sidebar over the view content and not to shift it? Just like it's implemented almost in any mobile apps, e.g. in Gmail or Telegram?

BTW, the sidebar in the UI5 documentation also is shown over the page content in the mobile mode.

Comment: There seems to be a custom control - alternative: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/09/06/creating-a-sliding-panel-control-with-sapui5-part-1/